# How can I configure the Windows' "GUI is not responding" dialog?

Tags: windows, multithreading, customization, multilingual

In these rare cases where a long I/O operation is performed with a possibly corrupted disk,
I change the mouse cursor to Hour Gloss.

However if the user keeps clicking, the windows shows the "GUI is not responding" dialog:

[image: "GUI is not responding" dialog]

I need to prevent the option of "Close the program" from this dialog.

Can anybody kindly help?

Comment: Your only option is to perform the I/O task on a different thread.

Comment: The question is how to get rid of the error dialog. 

I do not want to develop cancel/progress handling in this specific case. It is not important enough. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You get rid of the dialog by not running into the condition on which it is displayed.  You can potentially [get rid of the symptoms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997310/busy-application-leads-to-false-not-responding-state-on-windows-7-wm-update), but the disease will remain.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for the link. I will try it and report the results...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to perform your IO operation in a different thread and disable your GUI buttons (and maybe add some progress bar or loading screen, something like that). When the IO thread finishes the work it can notify your UI and the user can continue the work.

Best Regards,
Pedro Gandola